# Using normal series of a group to build it up via extensions

Tags: finite-groups

In the context of normal and subnormal series I've found the following:

"From a finite subnormal series of a group $G$ we obtain a sequence of exact sequences and thus $G$ is built up out of the quotients factors of the sequence by forming successive extensions."

Which is the formalism to express this group $G$ by this way?

Answer (score 0):

$$N\triangleleft G\Longrightarrow\,\text{we get the exact sequence}\,\, 1\longrightarrow N\stackrel{i}\longrightarrow G\stackrel{\pi}\longrightarrow G/N\longrightarrow 1$$

with $\,i=\,$ the embedding injection and $\,\pi=\,$ the natural (surjective, of course) projection.

Now do the same as above for any subnormal series and every two elements in it.

Comment: Ok. I did. This is the first part of the claim. What about the part "G  is built up out of the quotients factors of the sequence by forming successive extensions" ??

Comment: Do you kinow what does "The group $\,G\,$ is an extension of some (normal) subgroup $\,N\,$ by a group $\,K\,$" mean? Take a peek at this site:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension

Comment: I also know what that means. The problem is with the part "built up out of the quotients factors".

Comment: You said "Now do the same as above for any subnormal series and every two elements in it".But this is the exactly point which I don't know what to do next. What should I do after that?